# Can two detectors for gravitational waves be combined into a very long baseline interferometer?

Tags: gravitational-waves, interferometry

While detectors for gravitational waves are interferometers themselves, the question here is about an increase in resolution resulting from two or more detectors far away from each other.

Comment: I did not vote, but I think this question would be greatly improved by adding a bit more detail. In particular, I cannot think right now which signals would be used for the interferometer of interferometers.

Answer (score 3):

They do use two or more detectors to triangulate the origin of a source. Most recently the Advanced Virgo detector in Italy was used in conjunction with the two LIGO detectors in the USA. This has been published in *Physical Review Letters* ([Phys. Rev. Lett. 119, 141101 – Published 6 October 2017](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.141101)).

With two detectors the sky area for "pinpointing" the source is quite a large area, but with three detectors the area is reduced by a factor of about 20.